# How to upload objects to private s3 bucket using nodejs and AWS SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload images to private s3 bucket through nodejs using AWS SDK, but i am getting access denied error.

Comment: You need to have a bucket policy with proper access for your user/role. More: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-policy-language-overview.html

Comment: What makes you think that the app should have access? What permissions are associated with the credentials being used by the app?